# Make typescript interface extend another interface excluding keys already defined

Tags: typescript, interface

For some hacky scripting on my iPhone (*not* code I would ever write for production), I frequently find myself treating `string`s as `string[]` (a character array).  Since typing on a phone is significantly slower than on a keyboard and characters are at a premium given the 57-character-wide screen size, I wrote some code that takes every method of `Array.prototype`, maps it to `Array.from(this)[fn]`, and attaches it to `String.prototype` *if it does not already exist*.  For example, I want `.slice()` still to return a `string`, not a `string[]`.

```js
Object.entries(
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Array.prototype)
)
  .filter(([n, d]) =>
    !(n in String.prototype) &&
    typeof d.value === 'function'
  )
  .forEach(([n]) =>
    String.prototype[n] = function (...args) {
      return Array.from(this)[n](...args)
    }
  )
```

Now I can run `'abc'.filter(x => x !== 'b')` and receive `['a', 'c']`.  Huzzah.

Now I want to write the updated `interface String` without manually copying over every valid declaration from `Array<T>`.  (*Sometimes* [play.js](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/play-js-javascript-ide/id1423330822) will read a `.d.ts` file.)

My best attempt introduces circular type references, which doesn't surprise me.

```
type MethodNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T & string]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? K : never;
}[keyof T & string];

type MethodsOf<T> = {
  [K in MethodNames<T>]: T[K];
};

type CharArray = Omit<MethodsOf<Array<string>>, keyof string>;

declare global {
  interface String extends CharArray {}
}

export {};
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATAcgQwLYQM4B4AVAPigF4oBvAKCigG0BpKASwDsoBrCEJAMyiEoAMii5gAJ3YBzALoAuQU1lQIAD2AQ2KXFAAUAOiMYJ03IoxsQ9WQEpypSyCgB+KM0VsIANwgSA3NQAvvTcvAJCouJSbHKB1KCQsPDIOgDyfESkFDR0TKwccIiomDgEJApKjLKBQfGJ0ADCCCYAghISGM4UaVgswPhFqbgZ+O2dIPjRMsTEADRcPPxikjPxKBAAxgA2JtDS20gARhjbVLQFmhJ8GJvQAMqrsaoaWjpQzW0dXVRBwdTUdRgJASYC-fxAA)

Up until I make `String` extend `CharArray`, everything works fine.  `CharArray` has the proper methods.  Once I add the extension, `CharArray` tries to exclude its own members, since those members are now members of `String`.

Is what I'm asking even possible?  I *suspect* the answer is *no*, but I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mere seconds before posting this question, an idea occurred to me, and it works.  Rather than excluding `keyof string` (which is what `Omit` does), make `CharArray` use `string[K]` if it exists.

```
type CharArray = {
  [K in MethodNames<Array<string>>]: K extends keyof string ? string[K] : Array<string>[K];
};
```

Now, while the engine *could* argue a circular reference, it's only merging the properties of `string` with themselves, so it doesn't care.  (At least, I think that's the reason.)